# how to set value to @Order annotation in spring boot from a propertyfile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to autowire the following beans to a `List`, and I need my `List` to be ordered. This is how I'm doing it:

```
@Service
@Order(1)
public class Slave1 implements Slave {}

@Service
@Order(2) //instead of hardcoding I need the value to be picked up externally
public class Slave2 implements Slave {}

@Autowire
List<Slave> slaves;
```

But I want the order value to be fetched from the `application.properties` file.
Is this possible? Can I set a value for the `@Order` annotation from a property file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) for `Order`, includes the line:

> Ordering strategies within the Spring container, on the other hand, are typically based on the Ordered interface in order to allow for programmatically configurable ordering of each instance.

So, if you're able to implement the [`Ordered` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html)  as well in your `Slaves`, this is easily achievable.

With your code I tried the following, which seems to work:

Make the `Slave` interface extend `Ordered`:

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;

public interface Slave extends Ordered {
}
```

Then have your individual slaves implement the `getOrder()` method, returning a value that's set with an `@Value` taken from your `application.properties` file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Slave1 implements Slave {
    @Value("${slave1.order}")
    private int myOrder;

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return myOrder;
    }
}
```

And then in `application.properties`:

```
slave1.order=1
slave2.order=2
```